# How to enable Selection for a GridView that assigns the DataSource in the code behind class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I noticed that when I create a GridView that I am given the option to "Enable Selection" as long as I choose a DataSource in the GUI. However, I am binding the DataSource in the code behind class.

I added SelectMethod="GetCustomers" to my GridView control and an empty GetCustomers() method to my code behind class but I don't see a "Select" link appear in my GridView.

How can I enable "Selection" for my GridView if the DataSource is being bound in the code behind?

I should probably also mention that my data is coming from my NorthwindDAL.GetCustomers() method which is returning a List of type .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
 GridView1.AutoGenerateSelectButton = true;
```

set the above properties to true and ofcourse, welcome to StackOVerFlow

Comment: Thanks :). Do you know if there is a way for me to accept the answer?